# Real time data streaming from OpenSearch

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, opensearch

I have a requirement where I need to stream real time live updates from the opensearch database. I have thought of implementing it using spring-data-elasticsearch reactive API(Opensearch client) and by using spring webflux library.

I just need to know whether spring data elasticsearch API will pull the real time live data from opensearch instance.Like if any changes happens in opensearch instance,that also should be reflected in real time.

At a high level,I need to know whether the new changes pushed to opensearch instance will also be streamed real time by using spring-data-elasticsearch reactive API.

Please let me know if there is any other best approach to deal with this issue.

Architectural design:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDS3V.png)

tech stack used:
1.Spring webflux
2.spring-data-elasticsearch
3.Using Rsocket protocol for real time data streaming.

I have thought of implementing it using spring-data-elasticsearch reactive API(Opensearch client) and by using spring webflux library.
I just need to know whether spring data elasticsearch API will pull the real time live data from opensearch instance.
Like if any changes happens in opensearch instance,that also should be reflected in real time.